# Gaussian measures from a finite dimensional space to an infinite dimensional space

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, gaussian-integral

It's well known that the characteristic function of a gaussian measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is given by:
$$
\hat{\mu}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}exp(i\xi . x)\mu (dx),\qquad  \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
but when we move to an infinite dimensional space; let's say a Banach space $X$ the formula becomes:
$$
\hat{\mu}(f)=\int_{X}exp(if(x))\mu (dx),\qquad  f\in X^*
$$
My question is how such formula has been derived ? what analysis leads to this standing on the finite dimensional result ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you know about $(\Bbb R^d)^*$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins it's a banach space if it's that the aim of your question !

Comment: More to the point, each element of $(\Bbb R^d)^*$ is of the form $x\mapsto \xi\cdot x$ for some (unique) $\xi\in\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins so you're saying that the inner product defined in the first formula is an element of $(\mathbb{R}^d)^*$ and hence they took an element of $X^*$ as a generelization ?!

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying.